# Using SimonVT number picker and unable to inflate xml

Tags: java, android, xml

So I'm using  [SimonVT number picker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) to try and create a number picker that works with gingerbread.  Unfortunately when I try to set it up as a dialog, it crashes when it tries to inflate the xml.  I honestly have spent a while on this and cannot for the love of me figure out.  Can anyone else?

This is where it crashes:

```
import net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.View;

public class setSnoozeMethodDialog extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.set_snooze_dialog, null);

    NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    np.setMaxValue(20);
    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setFocusable(true);
    np.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    builder.setView(view);

    return builder.create();
}
```

This is the xml that is having trouble being inflated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center">

<net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the error

```
01-07 23:44:33.308: E/AndroidRuntime(623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 23:44:33.308: E/AndroidRuntime(623): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker
01-07 23:44:33.308: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
01-07 23:44:33.308: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
01-07 23:44:33.308: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-07 23:44:33.308: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-07 23:44:33.308: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-07 23:44:33.308: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
```

I put these in my manifest already

```
        <activity
        android:name="net.simonvt.numberpicker.samples.DarkThemeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SampleTheme" />
        <activity
        android:name="net.simonvt.numberpicker.samples.LightThemeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SampleTheme.Light" />
```

This is in my theme.xml in value folder

```
<resources>

<style name="SampleTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
</style>

<style name="SampleTheme.Light" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.Light.NumberPicker</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  I needed to add

```
<resources>

<style name="SampleTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item> </style>

<style name="SampleTheme.Light" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.Light.NumberPicker</item> </style>
```

to my styles file, not the theme file.